# Requests.get error when reaching an arduino Web Server. What's the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

I want to read a request-answer sent by arduino with python.

I have already wrote a code for arduino in which arduino process a HTTP request and send the answer.
This is the part of that code

```
String answer ="";    
answer += "RQ.";
answer += nreq;
answer += ".STATE.";
answer += req_state;
answer += ".";
client.print(answer);
```

so the answer is

```
RQ101.STATE.3.
```

Python Code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get 
('http://192.168.1.200/NQ.101.IDX.003.TI.1.N.001.STOP')
```

then i will write

```
print(r)
print (r.text)
```

I will expect

```
RQ101.STATE.3.
```

The actual output is attached by image (had to put it by link because of posting limitation)
[CODE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idmhm.png)

Works well with a real site (for example http://www.google.com)
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: what is `client`?

Comment: Already resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i forgot to put header in client answer (server side).